# Change the selected item to next or previous

Tags: vba, outlook

I wrote code below that is very similar to the [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181986/what-is-the-best-way-to-organise-e-mails-in-ms-outlook). It marks emails and meeting responses as read and moves them to the archive.

I sort my mail by newest on top. After using the macro, the selection defaults to the next email down (the older one). I want it to move to the next email up (the newer one). If I reverse the sorting order of emails, then it works how I want it to. I've dedicated too much time to this to just reverse the sorting order of my emails.

I tried to set a MailItem to Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Items.GetNext then use MailItem.Display. This opens rather than changes selection, doesn't know current selection, can't figure out what's considered "next".

I tried setting the Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item property. I've been through (MSDN and Expert*sexchange*) looking for a solution.

```
Sub MoveToArchive()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace, objItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objMRItem As Outlook.MeetingItem
    Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objFolder = objNS.Folders("Archive").Folders("Inbox")

    If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each objItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        If objFolder.DefaultItemType = olMailItem Then
            If objItem.Class = olMail Then
                objItem.UnRead = False
                objItem.Move objFolder
            End If
        End If
    Next

    For Each objMRItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        If objFolder.DefaultItemType = olMailItem Then
            If objItem.Class = olMeetingResponsePositive Or olMeetingResponseNegative Or olMeetingResponseTentative Then
                objMRItem.UnRead = False
                objMRItem.Move objFolder
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Set objItem = Nothing
    Set objMRItem = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objNS = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outlook provides no way to programmatically select a particular item in the Explorer window.
So you would be able to do it this way. The only way I think that you could do it would be to programmatically press the previous key on the tool bar or menu. or redesgin the app to archive in the inspector etc.

Comment: Can you expand on your thought of archiving in the inspector? Thanks

Comment: you could add an archive button to the toolbar or ribbon. you can then close the current item and open the next or previous item.
in the explorer view you could add an arcive folder or archive multipul items and then use the current selection. also you could use context menus in the explorer view.

Answer (score 2):

Insert into your code one of the two lines of SendKeys code from one of the following two macros to cause Outlook to change the selection in the Outlook Item List pane to the message above or below the active message. The email message item you are moving up or down from must be active in the Item List pane in the Outlook application before the SendKeys code executes. If necessary add a time delay in your code to allow time for the appropriate message to become active in Outlook before the SendKeys code executes. These macros could also be added to the ribbon in Outlook 2010 to create up and down arrow buttons to navigate in the Outlook Item List Pane.

--
Sub MoveUp()

SendKeys "{UP}": DoEvents

### End Sub

Sub MoveDown()

SendKeys "{Down}": DoEvents

### End Sub

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve a similar effect by using the SendKeys function.

I wanted to return to the first message in the explorer, after doing some manipulation of the selected items.

I just added the following line after the manipulation is done:

```
SendKeys "{HOME}"
```

This works for me, on this particular case but can be modified to be used in other context.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook **does** indeed provide a way to select a particular item in the Explorer window with VBA using the method "ActiveExplorer.AddToSelection". The fiddly bit is to identify which item you want to add.

This sample code is something that may get you onto the path of being able to select items in the Outlook Explorer Window. It will need editing to suit your circumstances and no doubt could be neater, however it is potentially more reliable and versatile than using SendKey commands to control the application.

```vb
Function ExampleNavigateNext()
    On Error GoTo ErrorTrap
        
    Dim nsp As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim itm As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim itmSelected As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim fld As Outlook.Folder
    
    Dim intCount As Integer
    Dim strFilter As String
    
    Dim objItems As Folder
    Dim objFiltered As Items
    
    Set nsp = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set fld = ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
    Set objItems = fld
    
    If ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count > 0 Then
        Set itmSelected = ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
    Else
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    ' Dimension intItemCount As Integer in the Declarations Section (top) of  the Module Window in the VBA IDE
    intItemCount = intItemCount + 1
    
    ' Filter the items in the folder if required. For example, this filters out mail that has no category allocated.
    strFilter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#Keywords" & Chr(34) & " is null"
    Set objFiltered = objItems.Items.Restrict(strFilter)
    
    ' This sorts the filtered items into "newest first" which is the way many people have their mail presented in the explorer dialog.
    objFiltered.Sort "SentOn", True
    
    ' This sets the variable "intItemCount" to the next item - ie if you don't have the first item selected.
    For intCount = 1 To objFiltered.Count
        Set itm = objFiltered(intCount)
        If itmSelected = itm Then
            intItemCount = intCount + 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
        
    ' Identify the item you want
    For intCount = 1 To objFiltered.Count
        Debug.Print objFiltered(intCount).Subject
        Set itm = objFiltered(intCount)
        If intCount = intItemCount Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    
    If itm Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    ' Clears all current selections
    ActiveExplorer.ClearSelection
    
    ' Selects the item you require (with luck)
    ActiveExplorer.AddToSelection itm

ExitHere:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set nsp = Nothing
    Set fld = Nothing
    Exit Function
ErrorTrap:
    If Err.Number = 0 Then ' Catch errors here if necessary
    Else
        Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
        Stop
        Resume
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Best I found was to use send keys for the standard keyboard shortcuts

> Switch to next open message:       Ctrl+Period (.)
>
> Switch to previous open message:   Ctrl+Comma (,)

So, one of:

```
SendKeys "^."
SendKeys "^,"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are in folder like inbox and you have sorted by date, you can use  some similar :

```
Sub MovePrevious()
'------ by t2t2t2------
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966887/change-the-selected-item-to-next-or-previous/75821607#75821607

' On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
'move to previous if is sorted by date
Dim CurrentSelected, NewSelected As Outlook.mailItem
Dim itemsCount, i As Long           'Dim strFiltr As String
Dim allInFolder As Items
   
    If ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count > 0 Then                                  'if nothing selected, then exit sub
        Set CurrentSelected = ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
    Else
        GoTo ErrorHandler
    End If

    Set allInFolder = ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Items                        ' posible filtering : ...Items.Restrict(strFilter)
    allInFolder.sort "SentOn", True                                             'false = ascending, true= descending, sorting by "SENT on",
    'Debug.Print (CurrentSelected.EntryID & vbCrLf & CurrentSelected.Subject & vbcrlf)

    itemsCount = allInFolder.Count                                              'set count of all items (emails) in     folder
    If allInFolder.Item(itemsCount).EntryID = CurrentSelected.EntryID Then      'if is  selected first item then exit. not possible select previous
        GoTo ErrorHandler
    End If

    For i = itemsCount To 1 Step -1                                             'go through all mails and find     current selected email
        If allInFolder.Item(i - 1).EntryID = CurrentSelected.EntryID Then       'see previous(i-1) ENTRYID from active(i) entryID.
                                                                                'if previous (i-1) has the same id like current selected(i), then set the new selected from (i)
           Set NewSelected = allInFolder.Item(i)
           Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    ActiveExplorer.ClearSelection                                               ' Clear current selections
    ActiveExplorer.AddToSelection NewSelected                                   'select  previous =     newSelected

ErrorHandler:                                                                   'clear the variables and empty from memory
    Set CurrentSelected = Nothing: Set NewSelected = Nothing
    itemsCount = Empty: i = Empty 'strfiltr=empty
    Set allInFolder = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `clearselection` and `addtoselection` like this

```
Call e.ClearSelection
For Each itt In e.CurrentFolder.Items
    'MsgBox CStr(itt)
    If (e.IsItemSelectableInView(itt)) Then
        If itt.FullName = it.FullName Then
            Call e.AddToSelection(itt)
        End If
    End If
Next
```