# Automating outlook

Tags: .net, vba, outlook

a task was thrown in my lap that requires me to:

1. Iterate through many (1000's) of message folders in outlook 2010
2. for each folder in a specific subfolder, right click a menu, select export as pdf (this is a plugin "DocumentExporter"), and click the ok button

I use outlook rarely, so I've never automated it to this extent.  I see you can do it with vba, and also potentially .net (i've installed the .net programmability extensions)

Any suggestions on the quickest way to go about this?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the `DocumentExporter` expose any COM API you could use from VBA? Because, if you really must automate your way through the context menu, this is going to get really ugly.

Comment: Thanks, I failed to mention that - no com interface, I was hoping it would because I agree completely it will get ugly - which is why I pose the question :-P

Comment: Okay, in this case this is gonna boil down to SendKeys, then.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966887/change-the-selected-item-in-outlook-to-next-or-previous) suggests that there is no way to programmatically select an item in Outlook. This rules out the SendKeys approach. From my perspective, you are doomed. :-\ Sorry to say that.

Comment: Thanks tomalak, I was able to do what I needed to do by sending ^A when in the message view (selects everything in the folder).  It's butt ugly, but so is this entire task.  Duct tape and bailing wire, but never doomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have Outlook here so the following is air-code.

```vb
Sub DoIt()
  Recurse ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder ' select relevant folder in Outlook first
End Sub

Sub Recurse(f as MAPIFolder)
  Dim sf As MAPIFolder

  PrintPdf

  For Each sf In f.Folders
    ' open a potential sub-tree of folders, and move down one folder in the UI
    SendKeys "{RIGHT}{PAUSE 100}{DOWN}"
    Recurse sf
  Next f
End Sub

Sub PrintPdf()
  ' open the context menu, go down 4 entries, press enter, wait 10 seconds
  SendKeys "{APP}{PAUSE 100}{DOWN 4}{ENTER}{PAUSE 10000}"
End Sub
```

I have no idea if this will work, it's just an idea. Make sure that Outlook is in foreground while running this (by assigning the `DoIt()` routine to a custom toolbar button). The starting folder must be selected before you begin.

Comment: Thanks - this is basically what I did, after looking at this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SendKeys.aspx

Comment: +1 for coming up with the answer in "Air Code".  Shouldn't that be a badge?

Comment: I wound up running into all kinds of problems with send keys, and had to switch to the inputsimulator library from codeplex, which works much more reliably

Comment: After running all night, client says emails are all saved as pdf.  What a day.  :-P  Thanks for your help!